# SplitContainer com form ListBox como adicionar items?

Tags: vb.net

Como posso adicionar items em uma ListBox dentro de um form, e o form dentro de uma SplitContainer.

Button(Carregar ListBox) [home.vb (WindowsForm)]:

```
Dim naveg As New frmListBox
naveg.TopLevel = False
SplitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(naveg)
naveg.Show()
```

Button(Adicionar item) [home.vb (WindowsForm)]:

```
adicionarItems("Testando...")
```

ListBox [frmListBox.vb (WindowsForm)] 
está sem bordas e com listbox full ancora.

Functions [ex.functions.vb (Modules)]

```
Public Function adicionarItems(ByVal valor As String)
    frmListBox.ListBox1.Items.Add(valor)
End Function
```

Acima está todos os dados, como posso adicionar itens no listbox, dentro do Split? andei pesquisando, seria pelo Controls?

Answer (score 0):

### Primeira opção

Não entendi muito sua pergunta, mas você poderia criar um loop, verificando cada tipo de controle que estiver na SplitContainer, e após achar a Form, executar o comando. Segue o exemplo:

```
Public Sub AdicionarItem(ByRef Container As SplitContainer, ByVal oQueAdicionar As Object)
    For Each x As Control In Container
        If TypeOf x Is ListBox ' O Objeto é ListBox?
             CType(x, ListBox).Items.Add(oQueAdicionar)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

### Segunda opção

Você pode declarar essa ListBox como uma `WithEvents` pública, segue o exemplo abaixo.

Coloque essa linha abaixo da declaração de classe da sua Form inicial:

```
  Public Class Form1 'ou Home....
       Public WithEvents naveg As frmListBox
```

E esse código no Button(Carregar ListBox) [home.vb (WindowsForm)]:

```
  naveg = New frmListBox
  naveg.TopLevel = False
  SplitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(naveg)
  naveg.Show()
```

Ai o que você faz, cria esse método (é o mesmo, mas melhorado):

```
  Public Function adicionarItems(ByVal valor As String)
       Call Form1.naveg.Items.Add(valor)
       'Lembrando, que em "Form1" é o nome da sua classe inicial.
  End Function
```

Tente fazer isso, caso tenha dúvidas, comente aqui.